# Searching all cells in a column Excel with vbscript

Tags: windows, excel, scripting, vbscript

I wrote a vbScript to gather computer information for each user's computer on login, and Id like to have the script record the information to an Excel sheet on the server, with each computer having its own row.

I wrote this like 6 years ago but lost the script and havent touched vbScript since.

So what I need to do is,

1. check all the cells in column B (which would be computer name) that have a value
2. compare that value to value saved for the computer's name
3. if it matches, write the  computer info to that row
4. if there are no matches, then write the info to the first empty row

I have no idea where to start since vbScript is pretty foreign to me.

Edit - I have this loop so far and that echo to test it, but it only goes to 1, while I have like 6 rows with values in column 0. I tried that conditional to check the cell value for a value I know exists and I get a runtime error.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx")
Do While objExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(iRow,0).Value<>""
   WScript.Echo iRow
   If objExcel.Cells(iRow,0).Value = "three" Then
    WScript.Echo "three"
   End If
   iRow = iRow+1
Loop
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: obviously. I wasnt able to find anything useful but maybe my query wasnt effective.

Comment: yes. also, you need to read [ask], try something, post your code and ask for advices about it.

Comment: Take a look at [these scripts](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/excel/) how you can enter data to an excel sheet. Use [a (for) loop](http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/vbslooping) to iterate over the rows. **If** the correct cell is found **or** you encounter an empty cell **then** **exit** the **for** loop. Update the computername to the cell right of the last found cell.

Comment: You can use the `Range` object's `Find()` method to locate the correct row.

Comment: Why did you only post part of your code? You didn't even include how you got objExcel.

Comment: I didnt think that was pertinent but Ive added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your script, which makes the code fail silently.

As far as I can tell from your code this is probably what's happening:

- `Do While objExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(iRow,0).Value<>""`

  The script checks if the cell at the offset `(iRow,0)` of the active cell is empty and if it isn't goes into the loop.
- `WScript.Echo iRow`

  The script echoes the current value of `iRow` (probably 0).
- `If objExcel.Cells(iRow,0).Value = "three" Then`

  The script tries to access the **cell** `(iRow,0)` (**not** the cell at the **offset** `(iRow,0)`), which fails, because `Cells()` is not zero-based. The first row as well as the first column have the index 1 in the `Cells()` property. Not to mention that with `Cells()` you have to use the absolute row and column numbers, not the ones relative to `ActiveCell` as in `Offset()`.

To fix the issue I'd remove `On Error Resume Next` and simply use `Cells()` instead of `ActiveCell.Offset()`:

```
iRow = 1
Do While objExcel.Cells(iRow, 2).Value <> ""
  WScript.Echo iRow
  If objExcel.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = "three" Then
    WScript.Echo "three"
  End If
  iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: awesome dude, ok that was it!